# Clamping sprites in the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I want to clamp my sprite from disappearing from screen, but I am bit confused. I think I didn't understand concept of get_rect method properly. At this stage I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Thats my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()  

finish = False 
white = ( 255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
grey = (211, 211, 211)
font = pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/BRITANIC.TTF", 20) 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400)) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Game") 



line_speed = 2

line_pos_x = 100
line_pos_y = 0

end_pos = 170

player_x = 10
player_y = 10

player_move_x = 0
player_move_y = 0

dog_img = pygame.image.load("dog_brown.png")
dog_rect = dog_img.get_rect()


timer = pygame.time.Clock()

while finish == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_move_x = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_move_x = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_move_y = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_move_y = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_move_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_move_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_move_y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_move_y = 0


    player_x += player_move_x
    player_y += player_move_y  

    screen.fill(white)

    screen.blit(dog_img,(player_x, player_y))
    dog_rect.clamp_ip(screen)


    pygame.draw.line(screen,black,[line_pos_x,line_pos_y + line_speed],[100,end_pos + line_speed],5)
    line_speed = line_speed + 2



    pygame.display.flip()

    timer.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clamp_ip` needs another `Rect` as argument:

```
...
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400)) 
# create a Rect that represents the screen
screen_r = screen.get_rect() 
...
while finish == False:
    ...
    # use it instead of screen
    dog_rect.clamp_ip(screen_r)
    ...
```

---

Also, to have it work, you should get rid of the `player_x` and `player_y` variables and use the `dog_rect` Rect to keep track of the position of your player.

Instead of

```
player_x += player_move_x
player_y += player_move_y  
...
screen.blit(dog_img,(player_x, player_y))
```

simply do

```
dog_rect.move_ip(player_move_x, player_move_y)
...
screen.blit(dog_img, dog_rect)
```

Comment: I got rid of the error but it seems to ignore it and works as if this code weren't there.

Comment: Yeah, you don't actually use `dog_rect` to keep track of the position, so using `dog_rect.clamp_ip` makes no sense. I updated my answer.